How to retrieve and empty customer cart in WooCommerce after payment?
hello I made a plugin which follows that scenario :

1-client send data to payment gateway
2- gateway responses with url
3- client get redirected to that url
4- after payment server sends req with status to a webhook inside my plugin
5- my hook updates order status in admin
and this last thing I can't do : my hook empties the cart of the client
I tried alot and I dicovered the main problem , it is in sessions it can't get session to get cart
thanks in advance!

I tried to follow problem and found it is in sessions so we need a way to resolve it or find a new method to get cart and empty it
here is the code that I followed :
`<?php

add_action('rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route('custom/v1', '/empty-cart', array(
        'methods' => 'POST',
        'callback' => 'empty_cart_by_session_id',
        'permission_callback' => '__return_true',
    ));
});

function empty_cart_by_session_id(WP_REST_Request $request) {
    // Retrieve the session ID from the request body
    $session_id = $request->get_param('session_id');

if (!$session_id) {
    return new WP_REST_Response(array(
        'status' => 'error',
        'message' => 'Session ID is required.'
    ), 400);
}

// Initialize WooCommerce session if not already initialized
if (!WC()->session) {
    WC()->session = new WC_Session_Handler();
    WC()->session->init();
}

// Retrieve the session handler
$session_handler = WC()->session;

// Get the session data using the session ID
$session_data = $session_handler->get_session($session_id);

if ($session_data) {
    // Initialize the cart with the session data
    $cart_session = unserialize($session_data['cart']);

    // Check if the cart session is valid
    if ($cart_session && is_array($cart_session)) {
        // Set the cart session to the current session
        WC()->session->set('cart', $cart_session);

        // Initialize the cart object
        if (!WC()->cart) {
            WC()->cart = new WC_Cart();
        }

        // Empty the cart
        WC()->cart->empty_cart();

        // Optionally, you can update the session data back
        $session_handler->set('cart', WC()->session->get('cart'));

        return new WP_REST_Response(array(
            'status' => 'success',
            'message' => 'The cart has been emptied.'
        ), 200);
    } else {
        return new WP_REST_Response(array(
            'status' => 'error',
            'message' => 'Invalid cart session.'
        ), 400);
    }
} else {
    return new WP_REST_Response(array(
        'status' => 'error',
        'message' => 'Invalid session ID.'
    ), 400);
}

}
`

Welcome! Please add the code - by editing the question - that you think should empty the cart.
